# How to index (in FAST Search 2010 for SharePoint) multiple large custom columns with the same name

Tags: managed-metadata, fast-for-sharepoint

I am trying to add the same custom column ('Raw' in this case) to several different document libraries, and have these columns defined as custom metadata that gets indexed in the FAST Search Server. It seems that only the first custom column that I added is being indexed. Is it required that custom metadata columns have unique names, despite them being from different document libraries?

[EDIT]
With further research, it seems the FAST Search Server is only picking up on the same 5 documents that were originally indexed. Even when I add new documents to the same library as the five that are indexed, the new documents metadata is not indexed. Not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, feel kinda stupid about this.

It looks like I was forcing a full crawl of the 'FAST Queue' service application, which only indexes 'People' records, instead of the 'FAST Connector' service application.

Now that I have done a complete crawl in the right place, new documents and metadata is searchable. D'oh!